# Select Current Date + 10 and export this data as a new csv

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create VBA code that will select the Date, Day and Gas Usage columns (as depicted below) for the current day and the following ten days (TODAY()+10) (as highlighted in red by the below picture). Where this range can be copied and exported into a new csv file.

[image]

The code below performs this action of extracting a range and exporting it as a new csv, however, it only selects a static range (A1:C10). How can I edit the code so that when the VBA is run it will select these columns for the next ten days on any given day that this code is run.

```
Sub CreateCSV()
 
Range("A1:C10").Select

Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Add

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\lach\Desktop\Test\data" & Format$(Now, "yyyyMMddhhmmss") & ".csv", FileFormat:= _
        xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Are your dates in column A always sequential, without any gaps?

Comment: @BigBen yes they are, with no gaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your days are sequential, without gaps, you can use `Application.Match` to find the date and `Resize` to select that cell plus the next 10 rows.

```
Dim r As Variant
' Find the date in column A
r = Application.Match(CLng(Date), Range("A:A"), 0)

' Only proceed if date has been found
If Not IsError(r) Then
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = Workbooks.Add()
 
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(r, 1).Resize(11, 3).Copy _
       Destination:=wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

   wb.SaveAs _
       Filename:= "C:\Users\lach\Desktop\Test\data" & Format$(Now, "yyyyMMddhhmmss") & ".csv", _
       FileFormat:= xlCSV, _
       CreateBackup:=False
End If
```

Comment: This works, however it only exports the "Date" column

Comment: ooops, change to `.Resize(11, 3).Copy`, forgot you needed 3 columns.

Comment: perfect thank you! Just wondering if I wanted to select Today+1 onwwards, instead of the current day, is it easy to edit your Application.Match function?

Comment: Do you mean instead of Today+10? If so, you'd change to `.Resize(2, 3)` instead of `.Resize(11, 3)`. If I misunderstand and you want to find tomorrow's date, you can use `Date + 1` inside the `Match`.

Comment: Perfect Date +1 was what I meant, thanks heaps for your help!